# URL to a specific sheet for a Excel "Save a web page" export

Tags: html, excel, sharepoint

When a Excel file with multiple worksheets saving as web page, the htm (loading in sharepoint) shows the sheets as tag at the bottom.

When you click the tab you will see the sheet.

But what is the URL that can go directly to that sheet in IE/Chrome?

Comment: I am not familiar with this but are you able to right-click and go to "Copy Link Location" to find the address?

Comment: it gives you an URL that seems to have some reference to you sheets. For example, the URL is something like xxxxx/sheet002.htm. But if you copy & paste to a new browser, you will find that the page shows the 1st sheets instead

Comment: You may also want to try asking your question in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/